# Angular 2 date pipe

Tags: javascript, json, angular, date

I am using this code:

```
{{today | date:'General.dateFormat | translate'}}
```

where `General.dateFormat` is a format `MM.dd.yyyy` stored in my language JSON file. But it is printed as `5 22, 2017 AenerPMl.22PMteFor35PMt | trPMn24lPMte`

I think there is an issue with multiple pipe. If I replace `General.dateFormat | translate` with `MM.dd.yyyy` it works as it should. How do I give the format from my language json file using the translate pipe?

Comment: can you provide full example?

Comment: What example do you need in it? It's a simple 1 line code?

Comment: @MehulJoshi: please read Shahid's answer. It shows how 2 pipes can be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed translate pipe as a value to date filters. pass value directly instead of passing General.dateFormat as a string. please  try the below code

```
{{today | date: translate:'General.dateFormat'}}
```

Comment: Already tried that as well. I get Cannot read property 'dateFormat' of undefined

Comment: i have updated my answers please try now and let me know

Comment: can u tell me which library you used for translation ?

Comment: Shahid. YOu nailed it. Lovely friend. The final version which worked is this **today | date: translate:'General.dateFormat'**.

Comment: thanks please marked my answer it will help someone else